# Function won't compile. Is there a workaround?

Tags: compile

Here's a simplified form of a function I would like to compile, but it produces errors

```
DataType = Compile[{{Inputdata, _Real, 1}}, Module[{CIEL, CIEa, CIEb},
    dim = Dimensions@Inputdata;
    If[dim[[1]] > 3,
     {CIEL, CIEa, CIEb} = Inputdata
        ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

The error *Mathematica* produces is:

> Compile::extscalar: `dim=Dimensions[Inputdata]` cannot be compiled and will be evaluated externally. The result is assumed to be of type Void. >>

Is there a workaround to allow these types of functions to compile for conditionals that depend on the dimensions of a list?

Comment: You are setting global variables from inside the compiled function, I don't think that is possible, is that your intention? What should the function return?

Comment: @s0rce Nah, fixed that.  Looks like it should now.

Comment: If `(Dimensions@Inputdata)[[1]] > 3` then you can't set `{CIEL, CIEa, CIEb} = Inputdata` since `Dimensions@{CIEL, CIEa, CIEb} == {3}`.

Comment: @s0rce The error is above this part of the function. so change that to whatever and the error is the same

Comment: It compiles for me, try a fresh kernel. What version are you using, I'm using 9.

Comment: @s0rce both v9 and v10 Mac throw this same error

Answer (score 0):

Conditionals are fine in compiled functions...

```
DataType = Compile[{{Inputdata, _Real, 1}},
   If[Length@Inputdata > 3, 1, 0], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

DataType[{5, 6, 7}]

(* 0 *)

DataType[{5, 6, 7, 8}]

(* 1 *)
```

The problem is your function returns nothing, you are trying to set global variables from inside the compiled function and also you never use `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: Length won't work in this case.  I changed the variable names at the last minute and just chose the wrong names.  fixed

Comment: Isn't `Length` equivalent to the first element in the output of `Dimensions`?

Comment: It is but because dim is used multiple times I need Dimensions.